# Loading random Vertex in OrientDB

Tags: graph, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I need to load random Vertex or Edge record.

Is there any way to do this very fast?

Query

```
select @rid from User skip 300000 limit 1
```

is very slow.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this command

```
SELECT FROM <target> WHERE @rid > <lower-rid> ... [LIMIT <max-records>]
```

It should be faster.

for more info: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Pagination.html#use-the-rid-limit